# Issues with FragmentLayout crashing, never a working moment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

*EDIT2:
Updated the sources to the current snapshot. Issue is still persisting! (also changed by censor names as it was causing a little confusion, thats my bad i should have chosen the words better)*

---

*EDIT: 
the package name has been modified to protect an NDA. Its not actually com.private.fragment. Please assume along with me that all package names are intact and working correctly! Thanks*

I'm building for Gingerbread primarily, and I'm trying to figure out this Fragment thing (I'm using the v13 Compatibility Pack, which correct me if I'm wrong is just an updated version of the v4 Compatibility Pack) And honestly I just cant figure it out. In fact i get the

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
```

issue. 
I have a main.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/MainPage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/top_header" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SubHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/top_sub_header" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.private.thisishidden.IconList" >
        </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i have my main FragmentActivity

```
package com.private.thisishidden;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ThisIsHiddenActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I then have a list of icons in a scollable view layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/MainPage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Scollables"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/IconLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_search" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="NEAR ME" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_4" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="LODGING" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_1" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="ATTRACTIONS" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_events" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView4"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="EVENTS" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_7" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView5"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="WELLNESS" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_6" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView6"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="FOOD" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_8" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView7"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="SHOPPING" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_2" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView8"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="PLACES" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_9" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView9"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="CIRCLE" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_3" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView10"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="RECREATION" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_fav" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView11"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="FAVOURITES" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3sp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                            android:layout_width="65sp"
                            android:layout_height="55sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cat_5" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView12"
                            style="@style/MainPage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="INFO" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="35sp"
                android:src="@drawable/videoinfo" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then of course the corresponding class as defined in the main.xml

```
package com.private.thisishidden;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class IconList extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate layout
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_view, container, false);
    }

}
```

I've looked through all the examples and honestly this is just the last build that doesnt work, sort of at my wits end at the moment. 
So if someone can help point me in the right direction to getting fragments working, that would be awesome.

(obviously the error above happens the moment the app is launched)

PLEASE HELP!

EDIT 2: Not sure how much this will help but heres the LogCat output

```
11-24 10:49:09.501: W/ActivityThread(6998): Application com.private.thisishidden is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-24 10:49:09.521: I/System.out(6998): Sending WAIT chunk
11-24 10:49:09.551: I/dalvikvm(6998): Debugger is active
11-24 10:49:09.722: I/System.out(6998): Debugger has connected
11-24 10:49:09.722: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:09.922: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:10.122: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:10.322: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:10.522: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:10.723: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:10.923: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:11.123: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:11.323: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:11.523: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:11.734: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:11.934: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:12.134: I/System.out(6998): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:49:12.334: I/System.out(6998): debugger has settled (1429)
11-24 10:49:12.464: D/dalvikvm(6998): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 44K, 50% free 2715K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 37ms
11-24 10:51:51.810: I/dalvikvm(7311): Debugger is active
11-24 10:51:51.980: I/System.out(7311): Debugger has connected
11-24 10:51:51.980: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:52.180: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:52.390: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:52.590: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:52.791: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:52.991: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:53.191: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:53.381: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:53.591: I/System.out(7311): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-24 10:51:53.792: I/System.out(7311): debugger has settled (1431)
11-24 10:51:53.952: D/dalvikvm(7311): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 50% free 2715K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 29ms
11-24 10:52:13.881: D/AndroidRuntime(7311): Shutting down VM
11-24 10:52:13.881: W/dalvikvm(7311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.private.thisishidden/com.private.thisishidden.thisishiddenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1702)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at com.private.thisishidden.thisishiddenActivity.onCreate(ThisIsHiddenActivity.java:12)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     ... 11 more
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.private.thisishidden-2.apk]
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
11-24 10:52:13.961: E/AndroidRuntime(7311):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire error / stack trace

Comment: did you try to clean the project (to regenerate resources ?)

Comment: Added the LogCat output above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class needs to extend `FragmentActivity` and NOT `Activity` as you are using the compat lib.

**Edit** And rename your class from `FragmentActivity` given that this is the name used by the compat lib.

Comment: Updated the sources, same error "Error Inflating" to the current code above!

Comment: @DJDarkViper Try turning your fragment into say a `FrameLayout` and add your fragment into the container at run time, i.e. within `onCreate` of your `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

change `android:name="com.private.fragment.IconList"` to `class="com.private.fragment.IconList"` in main.xml

edit: he's using compat library so he <strike>**can not** use android:name</strike> ! edit2: apparently it's working in sdk 15

Comment: The error still persists, "error inflating class Fragment" line #45 happens to be in my main.xml and thats the <fragment line (being the only thing on that line). Is the fragment just in the wrong place to work? Also worth noting, is the cause is a "ClassNotFoundException" :\

Comment: " Is the fragment just in the wrong place to work?" no just inflater can't find your fragment class

Comment: Using `android:name` is OK, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Comment: See [fragment_hide_show_support.xml](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/res/layout/fragment_hide_show_support.html) in API support demos which uses `android:name`. If I'm missing something then I'm happy to stand corrected and vote your answer up but I've checked and ran this sample and it works. I'd appreciate your feedback, in terms of a comment, as to why my answer was voted down. Thanks. Peter.

Comment: See [fragment_layout_support.xml](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/res/layout/fragment_layout_support.html) in API support demos which uses `class` ... see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Example) ... anyway i'm sure that android:name was not working in some older SDK ...

Comment: problems still happening, at my wits end here. Apparently fragments are supposedly easy but I just cant get the bloody thing to work!